# Python live plot with 'plotfile' method

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot

I have to read numbers from "file.txt" in realtime (another program save a pair of numbers in it and overwrite them every 1/10 sec). The follow script can plot the numbers, but only the pair that read when I launch the plot. I tried with `plt.ion()` but it doesn't do anything in this case. I want to read every time that "file.txt" is updated.

The code I use is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plot.plotfile('file.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(1, 0), 
              names=('Volume', 'Tempo'), marker='o')
plt.show()
```

In case live plot can't be done with 'plotfile' method how can I do this? (I tried CSV methods and other stackoverflow solutions but the reading of the file fails everytime)

thanks

Comment: are you dead set on using a static file as your method of transferring data between programs? It relies on hdd writes that can be unpredictable due to caching, and is just inherently slow. Furthermore it provides no way to inform the plotting program when new data is ready..

Comment: also note... `.ion()` has nothing to do with re-reading the file and updating the data.. you'll have to do that manually

Comment: You should use [Matplotlib animation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is create some way to automatically loop over the file read and graph drawing operation. This could be accomplished with a for loop, but my preferred method would likely involve [`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation). For your case 10 fps is likely not fast enough you'll have to worry about blitting, but it's a good practice and will help you get much better speed out of MPL. The provided [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html) for `FuncAnimation()` uses blitting by only calling the artist for the line to be drawn to update it's y data. If you use `plt.plotfile()` it'll probably be much harder to just update the artist and have it get the new data properly, so I would recommend reading the data yourself, and calling `artists = plt.plot()` (or similar). This allows you to simply update the data of the line artist without re-drawing the whole graph: `lineartist.set_ydata(dataReadFromFile)`